# Power BI Embedded dates are not changing

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

After daily scheduled refresh, though dates are changing to reflect current day in Power BI Service. It's not happening in embedded reports. I have set up A2 capacity on Azure and using Rest API to integrate PowerBI reports into my application. Should I do any additional setting so that the embedded report also shows the current date after scheduled refresh?

Powerbi Service
[image]

Embedded Report
[image].

Comment: How is this report embedded?

Comment: @AndreyNikolov In node.js application using Power BI REST APIs

Comment: Push ctrl+shift+r to force the caches to refresh and your embedded report will then match PowerBI.com

Comment: @vvvv4d where should I do this force refresh? I tried in the browser but it didn't work.

Comment: @Gokul interesting. Since that did not work I am wondering if you have query caching enabled. Can you check and see if you do? If you do, turn it off and see if you get different results https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/power-bi-query-caching

Comment: Also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-data#datasets-in-directqueryliveconnect-mode

Answer (score 0):

Automatic page refresh is supported in PowerBI desktop and Powerbi service. Currently it is not supported in PowerBI Embedded reports. But You can use API `refresh()` method manually to get latest data, but it will work if your report is using Direct Query.

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-automatic-page-refresh
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/embedding-basic-interactions#refresh-a-report